# First jQuery plugin- How to handle events on re-initialization?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Well, this is not my first jQuery plugin but the first I think others would benefit from. So for me its the first time to make sure every possible application works as predicted.

My plugin handles modal less overlays and therefore has to listen for some events. If the plugin is re-initialized the old listeners seem to be still in place and cause malfunction.

**My solution to this looks like this:**

```
var oldSettings = $(_this).data('mlOverlaySettings');
if(oldSettings) {
    $(oldSettings.target).unbind('click.mlOverlay');
    $(document).unbind('click.mlOverlay');
    $(document).unbind('keyup.mlOverlay');
}
```

For me it seems like the problem has anything todo with saving the plugin state with the `$.data` function and not properly released references.

```
$(_this).data('mlOverlaySettings', settings);
$(_this).data('mlIsOverlayVisible', false);
```

**Additional resources**
[Plugin Demo](http://mloverlay.mythli.net)
[Plugin documentation and full source code](https://github.com/Mythli/jquery.mloverlay)

Unbinding the old event's is somewhat ugly. Am I doing something wrong here or is this always required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prevent reinitialization in the jQuery boilerplate method:

```
(function($) {
    var PLUGIN_IDENTIFIER = "my-plugin";

    ...plugin definition etc


    //jQuery boilerplate
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(opts) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var instance = $(this).data(PLUGIN_IDENTIFIER);
            //Prevent reinit on this element
            if (!instance) {
                instance = new MyPlugin(this, opts);
                $(this).data(PLUGIN_IDENTIFIER, instance);
            }
            //Method call
            if (typeof opts === "string") {
                instance[opts].apply(instance, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
            }
        });
    };
})();
```

You should always provide a `"destroy"` method that removes the .data and event listeners it added too. So it's only possible to reinitialize after calling `"destroy"` which conveniently removed the event listeners too.

Here's an example implementation of a pretty standard destroy method:

```
function MyPlugin(element, opts) {
    this.element = $(element);
    this.opts = $.extend(defaults, $(element).data(), opts);
    //Other instance state
    //absolutely do not use $.data for this, you should only occupy one $.data
    //slot for your plugin for the same reason you only occupy one slot on
    //$.fn
}
MyPlugin.prototype.destroy = function() {
    this.element.removeData(PLUGIN_IDENTIFIER);
    this.element.off(".myplugin"); //Remove all events off the element that belong to the plugin's namespace
    //.remove() any helper elements created by the plugin
    this.element = null;
};
```